# 16.04 - How do I install Canon Pixma MG3620 driver?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, canon, pixma

How do I install the driver for my Canon Pixma MG3620?

https://canon-ij.com/canon-pixma-mg3620-driver-download/

The printer works fine, but I'm trying to use the scanner (which has been saying "not detected")

@Garcia - What do I do on this part (after double-clicking the program) [image]

@GG - New error
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I though it would download .deb files directly but instead it's a "zipped" file that needs to be extracted. Answer edited.

Answer (score 2):

Download the two Debian packages [listed](https://canon-ij.com/canon-pixma-mg3620-driver-download/), one at a time, to the location (folder) you want. One is the scanner driver (ScanGear MP), the other is the printer driver (IJ Printer Driver).

Extract the packages (right-click > extract here).

Now open the extracted folder and inside it open the packages folder. There you will find two similar `.deb` files, one for 32-bit (i386) and other for 64-bit (amd64).

Right-click the one for your architecture. It will open the Ubuntu Software, click install.

Alternatively open the terminal, `cd` to the extracted folder and run the script `install.sh`. following example assumes you downloaded (and extracted) to the default Downloads folder:

```
cd /Downloads/scangearmp2-3.20-1-deb
sudo ./install.sh
```

Comment: @Garcia - What do I do on this part (after double-clicking the program)

Comment: Thanks, do I choose Open with Software Install or Open with Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: Any should do the job.

Comment: I installed both but it said "No devices found" then showed this error (added the screenshot to my original question at the top)

Comment: (1) Just in case run the installer as explained in the paragraph starting with *Alternatively...*. (2) The error is from HPLIP (drivers and software for HP printers), it has nothing to do with Canon. Do you have an HP printer/scanner/MFP also? If not, uninstall HPLIP. It shouldn't conflict anyway but who knows? Stranger things have happened.

Comment: And a question: Is the printer connected directly with a USB cable or networked (WiFi)? If the latter then please understand that there's no way to use the scanner via network, it must be with USB.

Comment: Can I drag the .deb things from the Desktop into the Downloads folder or do they have to be downloaded into the Downloads folder by default? I'm using an All-in-One printer/scanner/copier in 16.04, it's Canon Pixma MG3620 and I have the USB connected, it prints just fine but scanning is giving me trouble since it has been saying "No devices found" on everything.

Comment: The Downloads folder in the answer is there as an example. You can run the command from the folder where it actually is or copy/move the folder to anywhere else.

Comment: How do I uninstall HPLIP? Where do I get the correct driver(s)?

Comment: Sorry, this is getting a little weird... Drivers for what? This answer is about installing the drivers for the Canon printer and it really adds nothing to what the manufacturer says. HPLIP is drivers and software for **HP** printers.

Comment: How do I scan with my all in one canon pixma mg3620 printer? It lets me print with 0 difficulty but when I try to scan it says "No devices found." I read that I need to download something called "Canon IJ Network Tool" but I've only seen drivers for WIndows and OSX. I checked on the Canon website for drivers and it said this for Linux 64-bit: "There is no driver for the OS Version you selected. The driver may be included in your OS or you may not need a driver."

Comment: It's so confusing that it hurts, seriously. No, the network tool isn't necessary. And neither is HPLIP if you don't have HP printers Even if you do, you **don't use HPLIP software to scan with a Canon!**. Exactly which software are you opening in order to scan? (No need to keep repeating yourself about the printer model and that it prints but doesn't scans, we all can read it the 4 ? times it was posted, focus on *how* you're doing it and with *what*, assuming that you correctly installed the Canon's drivers and software).

Comment: You asked what I was using despite the title saying the name. 1. gscan2pdf. 2. XSane. 3. GIMP. I ran the terminal codes to get the printer working as soon as I got the printer.

Comment: It should work with XSane or SimpleScan. Nothing else to add.

Comment: Both XSane and SimpleScan say "no devices found." despite the USB being connected

Answer (score 0):

You can scan using the terminal.  In the terminal, type in:  scangearmp

It should bring up an option to select a scanner, if you don't see one, click the "Update Scanner List" button.  You should now be able to scan wirelessly.